# Javascript fetch response cutoff

Tags: javascript, android, json, react-native, fetch

I'm starting to learn react-native and ran into some problems while using fetch on Android.

```
try {
    let response = await fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
        method: "POST",
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            ***parameters***
        })
    });
    let responseJson = await response;
    if(responseJson){
        // console.log(responseJson);
        console.log(responseJson.text());
        // console.log(responseJson.json());
    }
} catch(error) {
    console.error(error);
}
```

The request is sent correctly but the answer isn't shown in it's totality:

```
(**loads more data before**){"ID":"779","DESCRICAO":"ZXCVB","CLIENTENUMERO":"10133","CLIENTENOME":"Lda 1","TREGISTO":"2015\\/11\\/24 09:34:15","TTERMO":"","SITUACAO":"C","TIPO":"P","NOTIFICACOES":"email","NOTIFI_TAREFA":"","ESFORCOS_TOT":"4","TEMPOGASTO_TOT":"0:01:44","TEMPOGASTO_PES":"0:01:44","PROJECTO":"New Products","USERNAME":"AT","UREGISTO":"S","EMCURSO":"0","TULTIMO":"2015\\/12\\/18 20:37:56","EQUIPA":"","NIVEL":"AVISAX"},{"ID":"783","DESCRICAO":"123","CLIENTENUMERO":"10133","CLIENTENOME":"Lda 1","TREGISTO":"2015\\/11\\/24 09:43:26","TTERMO":"","SITUACAO":"C","TIPO":"P","NOTIFICAC
```

As you can see, the JSON object isn't complete. Sending the same request using other methods in a browser returns the JSON correctly.

I'm wondering if this is an actual issue with fetch or with Android.

I've tried setting size and timeout parameters to 0 in fetch but it did nothing.

Edit: also tried using synchronous fetch instead of async, with the same effect:

```
fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ***params***
    })
})
.then((response) => response.text())
.then((responseText) => {
    console.log(responseText);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
}
```

Also tried:

```
console.log(responseJson);
```

and

```
console.log(responseJson.json());
```

Edit for further clarification:

When using response.json(), the response is shown as json (as to be expected) but it's still incomplete.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Edit :: Issue was with console.log limiting the number of characters it displays in the console.***

Quick question:

Can you get the json object in its entirety if you hit the endpoint with postman? It could very well be your server/service that is cutting off the message.

Lastly, (and I see you mentioned this above) but I always use the 'json' method off the response obj when I know that is the notation type - which should return a promise.

```
fetch(REQUEST_URL, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
        'Accept': 'application/json',
        'Content-Type': 'application/json'
    },
    body: JSON.stringify({
        ***params***
    })
})
//get the response and execute .json
.then((r) => r.json())
//then listen for the json promise
.then((j) => {
    console.log(j);
})
.catch((error) => {
    console.warn(error);
}
```

Let me know what happens and if you get the full response with postman (or fiddler compose).

Comment: Never used postman, just tend to use chrome's dev tools network thing. In chrome, the request responds with the full JSON, but I'm not using fetch there, using webix's webix.ajax().post() method.  EDIT: as for your recommended changes, I've tried that and it responds in a similar manner as response.json() that I mentioned I used as well. It prints the output as json instead of regular text but it still cuts off.

Comment: If you put a breakpoint in where you are doing console.log, can you evaluate the object to see if it is whole? I don't know how much data is in the "(**loads more data before**)" part - but, if it is a large amount it is possible that you are running into a character limit with console.log.

Comment: That was it. I was using atom with nuclide's logcat console and it was just not showing the whole thing. Did some operations with the json object and it handles perfectly fine. Cheers.